# password doesn't work for wireless in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, intel-wireless

I have installed 64-bit  Ubuntu 12.10. I have Intel cupertino-N 6150 wireless adapter.

At university, where I have no password, I am able to connect to the wireless network seamlessly, however at home, where I have a password, I cannot connect.

I am sure that the password I type is correct ( I rechecked the password on the other devices which connect)

I tried different security settings, still without any luck.

**Update**

After restarting the router my computer was able to connect to the network. Do not repeat my mistakes -)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

click on wifi icon, go to "Edit connections", go to "wireless" tab. Delete all the entries, click on "close". click wifi icon again, select your network and try connecting again.

---

ok then try this: press Ctrl-Alt-t; A terminal will pop up; type

```
rfkill unblock all
```

press enter

now restart network manager; type:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

press enter. It'll ask for your password, as you type it in there will be no feedback.  That's normal. Report back.

Comment: I tried, it didn't help.

Comment: It restarted the manager, but i am still not able to connect to the network. P.S. I appreciate your patience; these questions are outside of my expertise.

Comment: ok. before I ask you to run some diagnostic tools, let me ask the obvious: have you tried turning your router off and on again? :)

Comment: Wow, after I restarted It connected immediately. Thank you Sir. I apologize for taking so much time on such a fulish problem.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us. I'm glad it's working. I'm sure that you'll remember the on/off "solution" for future problems. It's strange how often it works.